# How to bring UIButton's titleLabel to front after adding CAShapeLayers as sublayer to it?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cashapelayer

here is the code for drawing `CAShapeLayer` and adding it to the `UIButton`:

```
let button = self.pickerButton as UIButton
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
let circlePath = UIBezierPath.init()//drawing the circle here
circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
button.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
```

using the following two methods to add text to the `UIButton` and bring it to front:

**Method 1**

```
button.setTitle("pick this one", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
```

**Method 2**

```
button.titleLabel?.text = "pick this one"
button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
button.bringSubview(toFront: button.titleLabel)
```

please point out if there is something being missed out. Thank you.

Comment: `[view.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];` will make your layer be inserted below all other layers instead of using `addSublayer`

Comment: @Brandon thank you, your answer worked for me!